# How to truncate a date to the beginning of week (Sunday)?

Tags: postgresql, date, truncate, dayofweek, weekday

I need to truncate dates to the start of week, which is Sunday in my case. How can I do this in PostgreSQL? This truncates to Monday:

```
date_trunc('week', mydate)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you subtract the `dow` value (`0` for Sundays, `6` for Saturdays) from the current date than you get the previous Sunday which is the begin of your Sunday-based week

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a3c101b6304ddd09bedad800c8d4984f)

```
SELECT 
    my_date - date_part('dow', my_date)::int
FROM
    my_table
```

[Further reading, documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Comment: One downside of this approach is that it will only work for `date` type, while `date_trunc` works with both `date` and `timestamp`.

Comment: Yes you are right. But you could cast the timestamp into date before the operation nonetheless because the time part will be truncated anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could truncate the date to the week's Monday, then subtract 1 day, e.g:

```
SELECT (date_trunc('week', now() + interval '1 day') - interval '1 day')::DATE;
    date
------------
 2019-06-16
```

As per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), `date_trunc()` accepts values of type `date` and `timestamp` and returns a `timestamp` (thus the cast at the end).